# Is that possible to get only 0 and 1 For multiclass multilabel problem in tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

Let's say I have 3 classes, and each sample can belong to any of those classes. The labels look like this.

```
[
    [1 0 0]
    [0 1 0]
    [0 0 1]
    [1 1 0]
    [1 0 1]
    [0 1 1]
    [1 1 1]
]
```

I set my output as Dense(3, activation="sigmoid"), and I compiled with optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy".
I guet 0.05 for loss, and 0.98 for accuracy, according to Keras output.

I thought I would get only 1 or 0 for prediction values if I use sigmoid and binary_crossentropy. However, model.predict(training-features) gave me values between 1 and 0 like 0.0026. I have tried all 4 combinations between categorical_crossentropy and binary_crossentropy with sigmoid and softmax. Model.predict always returns a value between 0 and 1 with shape of n_samples by n_classes. It would be 7x3 in the example above.

Then I clipped the values at 0.5 like below and checked accuracy_score(training_labels, preds). The score dropped to 0.1.

```
preds[preds>=0.5] = 1
preds[preds<0.5] = 0
```

I'd appreciate if someone could give me some guidance on how I should approach this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your description, this is a multi-label classification problem and therefore you should use `sigmoid` as the activation function of last layer and `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function. That's because we consider the classification of each label to be independent of all the other labels. Therefore, using `softmax` or `categorical_crossentropy` is wrong in this scenario.

The discrepancy between the accuracy reported by Keras and the accuracy computed using `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score()` function is not due to the rounding; actually Keras does the same rounding (or clipping) you have done for computing the accuracy. Rather, the difference is due to the fact that the `accuracy_score` function in multi-label classification mode only considers a sample as correctly classified when all the true labels and predicted labels for that sample match with each other. This has been clearly stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

> In multilabel classification, this function computes subset accuracy: the set of labels predicted for a sample must *exactly* match the corresponding set of labels in y_true.

However, in Keras [`binary_accuracy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/35093bc9bb14a66d09fe6ea26e302df8ffad64f4/keras/metrics.py#L26) function reports the average fraction of correctly classified labels (i.e. partial match is acceptable). To better understand this, consider the following example:

```
True labels  | Predictions | Keras binary acc | accuracy_score
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  [1 0 0]    |   [1 0 1]   | 2 correct = 0.66 | not match = 0.00
  [0 1 1]    |   [0 1 1]   | 3 correct = 1.00 | match     = 1.00
  [1 0 1]    |   [0 0 1]   | 2 correct = 0.66 | not match = 0.00
=================================================================
      average reported acc |             0.77 |             0.33
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. If I use sigmoid and binary_crossentropy, should I still have to manually clip (preds>=0.5 = 1, preds<05 = 0), or is there a better way  of doing it?

Comment: @jl303 You have to do that if you want to get the predictions as 0s or 1s (i.e. rounding cannot be done in the model). Though, one cleaner way of doing that after getting the predictions is to use [`np.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) function: `preds = np.around(preds)`.

Comment: Thanks @today! Round function is definitely cleaner! From digging the documentation you pointed out, I found label_ranking_loss and label_ranking_average_precision_score, but the scores are stil much lower than the loss and acc from Keras. Keras scores got me excited for a second, but SciKit-learn scores makes my model look very bad! :( In general, which metrics should I focus on improving for multilabel multiclass problems?

Comment: @jl303 You can get some insights from the [relevant section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics) in sklearn doc. It seems that the Hamming loss is a good option. Though, I think the metrics used for mult-label classification are not established as much as the ones used for multi-class classification or binary classification. You must search for the relevant multi-label classification datasets and their relevant papers and see what metrics are used to compare different methods.